# Predicting weather data using LSTM neural nets with Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I've spent months reading an endless number of posts and I still feel as confused as I initially was. Hopefully someone can help.

Problem: I want to use time series to make predictions of weather data at a particular location.

Set-up:

`X1` and `X2` are both vectors containing daily values of indices for 10 years (3650 total values in each vector).

`Y` is a time series of temperature at Newark airport (`T`), every day for 10 years (3650 days).

There's a strong case to be made that `X1` and `X2` can be used as predictors for `Y`. So I break everything into windows of 100 days and create the following:

```
X1 = (3650,100,1)
X2 = (3650,100,1)
```

Such that window 1 includes the values from `t=0` to `t=99`, window 2 includes values from `t=1` to `t=100`, etc. (Assume that I have enough extra data at the end that we still have 3650 windows).

What I've learned from other tutorials is that to go into Keras I'd do this:

`X = (3650,100,2) = (#_of_windows,window_length,#_of_predictors)` which I get by merging `X1` and `X2`.

Then I have this code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(1,return_sequences=True,input_shape=(100,2)))

model.add(LSTM(4))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.compile(loss='mean_square_error',optimizer='rmsprop',shuffle=True)
model.fit(X,Y,batch_size=128,epochs=2) # Y is shape (3650,)

predictions = model.predict(?????????????)
```

So my question is, how do I set up the model.predict area to get back forecasts of `N` number of days in the future? Some times I might want 2 days, sometimes I might need 2 weeks. I only need to get back `N` values (shape: `[N,]`), I don't need to get back windows or anything like that.

Thanks so much!

Comment: So your Y value is `t=100` for the first input...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only format in which you can predict is the format in which you trained the model. If I understand correctly, you trained the model as follows:

You used windows of size 100 (that is, features at times `T-99,T-98,...,T`) to predict the value of the target at time `T`.

If this is indeed the case, then the only thing that you can do with the model is the same type of prediction. That is, you can provide the values of your features for 100 days, and ask the model to predict the value of the target for the last day among the 100.

If you want it to be able to forecast `N` days, you have to train your model accordingly. That is, every element in `Y` should consist of sequences of `N` days. [Here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/multi-step-time-series-forecasting-long-short-term-memory-networks-python/) is a blog post that describes how to do that.

Comment: What do you think about running it in open mode for N days?

Comment: @user3684792 you can do that as well, but then you need to provide the appropriate features. That is, for the first day you need to provide features at times T-99,T-98,...,T (here I denoted the first day by T). For the second day you need to provide features at times T-98,T-97,...,T+1. And similarly for each one of the other days until N. The format of the input should be the same format that you used for training.

Comment: Do you have any intuition as to the accuracy of this vs re-training? I guess I would expect it to be worse

Comment: If by "re-training" you mean retrain with Y consists of sequences of size N, then I would expect the accuracy of re-training to be worse (it is harder to predict N days ahead than predicting 1 day ahead). On the other hand, re-training will enable you to forecast further. That is, you will be able to forecast N days ahead instead of 1 day ahead (so if N=30, you can make a forecast for the whole May even if your features are available only until the end of April. You'll have to test the model to see if the forecast is good).

Comment: (continuing) So it really depends on the purpose of your model. Each approach has its advantages and disadvantages.